# PHP arraw access doesn't work on GoDaddy PHP 5.3.1

Tags: php

On my GoDaddy shared hosting space, I cannot run the following simple PHP code line:

```
$debut = split(" ", $_GET ["debut"])[4];
```

it generates the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/....../html/test.php on line 4

This code line works on my local development environment (XAMPP) !

- GoDaddy: PHP 5.3. I
- Local XAMPP: PHP 5.5.0

Am I forced to change hoster ? (Was my first time using GoDaddy and i only had problems so far)

Thanks for any help !

Comment: That requires PHP 5.4 to derefernce from a function call as in `function()['key']`

Comment: Also, please turn up error reporting [since `split()` was long ago deprecated](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). You ought to be seeing warnings about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change into a two-liner:

```
$debut = split(" ", $_GET["debut"]);
$debut = $debut[4];
```

Comment: You missed $ symbol in your result..,

Comment: Now generates: 
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /home/content/47/....../html/test.php on line 4

Comment: @Tuthmosis See the comment by  Michael Berkowski.

Comment: @Tuthmosis There are lots of alternatives to the old `split()` which are in the _see also_ section of the docs linked above.  Make sure you have error_reporting turned on and all the way up to E_ALL on your local development machine, because you would have seen that warning to begin with.

Comment: Ok i was suspecting something like that... Will get rid of the "split" and use... What array_splice i guess ?... And i'll turn error reporting ON on my local setup... Thanks... your initial comments can be turned to official answer.

Comment: functions as arrays are available since PHP 5.4